# Java Functions, Returns, and Optionals

Tags: java, javascript

I am trying to create a client library that reads JSON from an external file online. I already know about the function interfaces and optionals, but I was wondering if there is a way to allow users to supply callback functions such that the parent function exits completely. For JavaScript, such a function is as follows:

```
file.read('hello', function(err, data) {
    // something here
});
```

Basically, I wish to do the same in Java. How can I do this such that the error callback supersedes the read function? What I mean is that in the event that the error callback is called, then read should not return a value at all. If the callback is not called then the read should return the value.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely, totally different languages. There's really no significant similarity between the two, and in particular the way you do I/O is totally different.

Comment: So there's no sort of combination of void and String per say such that nothing is returned on error, and String is returned otherwise?

Comment: Again, you need to understand that there is almost nothing in common between Java and JavaScript. They are totally, completely different.

Answer (score 0):

In Java upto 1.7 the only way to achieve javascript like callbacks is thru interface. The api user who calls your method read has the liberty of implementing what he feels needs to be done to handle the error by writing an implementation class for the interface at the invocation point.

```
public String read(String options,IErrorCallBack errorHandler) throws Exception {
    try {
       // When everything works fine return what you think should be returned.
        return "Success";
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        // On Error call the function on the error handler.
        errorHandler.doSomething();
        throw e;
    }
}

public interface IErrorCallBack {
    public void doSomething();
}

// The invocation point.
read("myString", new IErrorCallBack() {
    public void doSomething() {
        // Your implementation.
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think you can return in a try statement.

Comment: Can you please explain more on what you mean "i dont think you can return on try".

Comment: You definitely can return in a try. However, I don't think this is legal code because in Java you have to exit a method by either throwing an exception or returning which this doesn't do.

Comment: My bad. You can return in a try but there also has to be one outside of the try.

Comment: My Bad, I didnt add the throw.

Comment: If you also want to return on the exception, all you have to do is design the   interface in that way. You can have a Pojo class Response that has Success and Error class as properties. And both you method and call back method can return the Response object populating sucess / error object based on the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the user pass in a function and then just not do anything with it if there is no error.

This example assumes that you have a custom class called `Error` that the caller is aware of and would like to interact with in case of an error.

```
public void read (String str, Function<Error,Void> errorFunc)
{
    //interact w/ libraries, boolean error = true or false
    //if there is an error, variable err of type Error contains information
    if (error)
    {
        errorFunc.apply(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to return when there is no error. I want to call the callback and forget read when there is one.

Comment: In that case probably the best you could do would be Optional.empty().

Comment: Is there a way to specify a set of possible return values such that I can return a Void or a String.

Comment: Wait a minute, can't I just make the return type Object, then I can use both Void and String?

Comment: Yes. In my opinion a Java programmer is not usually expecting something like this though.

Comment: I'm trying it and it doesn't seem that a Void instance can be returned.

Comment: Yeah...come to think of it I don't think you can instantiate a void. I think an Optional would be more standard.

Comment: That's my only option, no pun intended. I can't return nothing or something, I can only return something?

Comment: Yes. I think it's just a philosophical difference between JavaScript and Java's strong typing.

Comment: Bummer. I could have done this in a matter of seconds with Python. Wonder how they implement free type with when it is written in the statically typed C?